# Sharing doesn't work on Google Apps Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on Google Apps Script. I want to share the Google Apps Script Editor to another account.I use Chrome browser.

I clicked `File > Sharing` in the editor. But I got this error:

[image]

I tried to remove all the cache and cookies and histories from the browser. but, same.

Comment: If it is a standalone script, you can share the file inside Google Drive.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal Thanks. But it is notstandalone script. it's a script bound to a Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you want to share a script bound to spreadsheet you need to share the spreadsheet itself

- It is no possible to share a bound script is the spreadsheet is not shared
- If the spreadsheet is shared, there is no need to explicitly share the script

Comment: Thank you. But why a script bound to spreadsheet has sharing menu in its menu inside the GAS editor? It should be hidden if that is the spec, shouldn't it?

Comment: Accoring to Google [the current behavior](https://issuetracker.google.com/144825992) is intended and not a bug, but if you find it confusing, you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) asking for hiding the spec / providing a better error description. In the meantime, I hope that the provided solution helps you solving the problem.

Comment: I see that Google says this is not a bug. But it's confusing really. Thank you for the information.